# Как найти 3 самые сильные корреляционные связи в DataFrame pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

У меня есть DataFrame, нужно найти 3 самые сильные корреляционные связи. Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Ну как. Взять и посчитать коэффициент Пирсона, например. Каков вопрос, таков ответ. Где пример данных, в вопросе, где код ваш?

Comment: @strawdog, я знаю что есть метод .corr(), но он выводит все корреляции. А мне нужно, чтобы вывелись только 3 самых сильных. Мой код и данные в этом вопросе вообще никакой роли не играют.

Comment: Ошибаетесь. Отсутствие кода и данных в вопросе нарушают правила сайта.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так, наверное, данных вы не предоставили, поэтому искусственный пример:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(100, 10))
df_corr = df.corr()
corrs = [(df_corr.iloc[row,col], row, col) for row in range(1, 10) for col in range(row)]
max3 = sorted(corrs, key=lambda x: abs(x[0]), reverse=True)[:3]
print(max3)
```

Возможный вывод:

```
[(-0.3673189702279594, 3, 2), (0.23791763760252185, 7, 0), (0.20770926613674748, 9, 1)]
```

Суть:

- берём корреляции из нижней диагонали матрицы корреляции (ибо она симметричная, а на диагонали у неё вообще единицы),
- помещаем в кортеж каждый коэффициент корреляции и его координаты в матрице (т.е. сочетание каких это столбцов между собой)
- сортируем по абсолютному значению коэффициента корреляции
- берём три максимальных элемента

Если хотите получить названия столбцов, а не их номера, при выводе `row, col` преобразуйте в `df.columns[row]` и `df.columns[col]`. Ну или можете сразу в кортеж их класть.